# PHP How to retrieve first line of a .CSV as a string?

Tags: php, csv

How do I retrieve the first line of a .CSV file as a string?

This current method I am using is failing to return the first line, but is instead returning the second line:

```
$content = file($filepath);
echo $content[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will work better for you:
[fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

But on a large files and if you need the performance use this function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php

Comment: The OP wants a string, not an array.

Comment: Can I see an example of retrieving the first line as a string?

Comment: Ooops, I was wrong with the first function and you were the first with the second one :)

Comment: $handle = @fopen($filepath, "r");

if ($handle) {
    $line = fgets($handle);
}


// Your string is in the $line

Comment: What if that is returning the second line in the file? What does that mean?

Comment: Alex, it gets the line from the file pointer. fgets() reads the line and move pointer one line down.
Does any function read from the file using the same resource ($handle) in your code before?

It's easy to check it by just changing the $handle to let's say $hndl for both $handle =... and fgets($handle)

Comment: I changed the name of the $handle variable. No function uses the same resource previously in the script. Can I change the file pointer in the file so that it is pointing to the actual first line before I try to return it?

Comment: I have tried using the php rewind function on my handle, and when I output the handle it says it is 0, however it is still failing to return the first line! I am mind boggled at this point. $line is still the SECOND line, and not the first. I can even open this .csv file and look and see clearly that there is first line that is not getting returned and it has its own end line character.

Answer (score 5):

[`fgets()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) can be used to read a single line from a file.